# Node download and save gif

Tags: node.js

I want to download a gif from the net and save it in local drive.
So far I have:
1) getFile function that returns the gif as Buffer:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import https from 'https'
let url = '//some gif url'

const getFile = function(url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
        https.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = [];
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data.push(chunk);
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
                res(buffer)
            });
        }).on("error", (err) => {
            rej(err);
        });
    })
}
```

2) Saving function:

```
async function save() {
    let data = await getFile(url)

    fs.writeFile('./test.gif', data, (e, r) => {
        console.log(e,r) // null, undefined
    })
}

save()
```

The file is saved and have contents but when i try to open it it says: Could not load image....

I tried to convert the output as utf8 encoding but it gives me the same result.

***NOTE: I want to make it work with raw nodejs without 3-party tools or "pipe" to understand the working parts.***

I guess the problem is with encoding but i could't figure what exactly it is.

Thanks

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Do the first three bytes spell `GIF`?

Comment: No, i see \00\00\00ftypeisom\00\00isomiso2avc1...

Comment: Would I be correct in guessing this gif was attempted to be downloaded from imgur?

Comment: The exact url is: https://img.memecdn.com/i-amp-039-m-fine-yeah-fine_mp4_7153595.gif

Comment: OO i figured it's mp4 :). If i save the file as mp4 it works, even the extension is .gif. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Note that when you navigate to the URL, what loads is an mp4 file, not a gif. Change the extension to mp4 and you should be able to open the file in your system media viewer.